# Unity 5 checking for animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a player object and an enemy object, both have colliders on there body and on there weapons but this causes them to do damage when walking into each other. i would like to have is so they only do damage if the "isAttacking" animation is running. my code is attached to both the player and enemy object and is below:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class detectHit : MonoBehaviour
{

public Slider healthbar;
Animator anim;
public string opponent;
public Collider ecollider;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag != opponent) return;

        healthbar.value -= 20;

    if (healthbar.value <= 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isDead", true);
        ecollider.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
}
```

I've tried looking online but most stuff is out dated i feel i need to do something like this:

```
if(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("isAttacking")){
healthbar.value -= 20;
}
```

but this isn't working, maybe as i'm not getting it to look at the opponents animation? i just don't know how to look for the enemy's animation if this is the case.

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add attack object and collider for the character in child. Turn off active for this collider in default.
If character start attack animation, turn on this collider in first frame. and turn off in last frame. 
 you can catch attack motion.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, if you want to check something in other scripts you need a reference to it. You could drag the enmemy GameObject/Prefab in the slot you store public attributes. You just need to have a public field of the type GameObject or you can even have the type set to Script.

```
public GameObject myEnemyReference;
```

When you don't have your enemy in the hirarchy of the scene, when you start and create the enemy by instantiating it via a script you must also store a reference.

```
GameObject toInstantiate = myEnemyPrefab;
GameObject myEnemyReference = Instantiate (toInstantiate, new Vector3 (0f, 0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

When you've got your reference you can just call a public function of the script you got like this:

```
detectHit enemyScript = (detectHit) myEnemyReference.GetComponent (typeof(detectHit));
bool isAttackState = enemyScript.checkForHitable ();
```

Here i just assumed that the script has a public function named checkForHitable, which returns true, when the opponent is allowed to take damage.

I don't understand how you want your fighting system to work, but since your code isn't working properly and you may want to check the animation state of both the player and the enemy, here's a suggestion of how you can check the enemys state or even further call functions of the enemys script, this may be helpfull later.

PS: class names usually start with upper case letters: DetectHit ;)